# Is it rude to ask if a task is done almost immediately after it was given?

Tags: management, manager, behavior

Is it rude to ask if a task is done almost immediately after it was given? I have a manager and this manager gets a lots of complaints from others, so I am not sure if I am the only one. And just recently he gave me a task and asked me if it was done after like 2 hours (it's a task that can take 3-4 hours at the very least), but I was already working on a critical task the same manager gave me the same day about 2 hours ago (shouldn't he remember that!?), so I was flabbergasted. This sounds rude, because he told me to no longer manage someone who was working under me when I found out he was lying about some work he supposedly had done, and because he's extremely unproductive at least 10 times less productive than me. When I keep asking why he's rude to me, he says it's because of cultural differences, but I don't think this is not considered rude in India. Am I crazy to think he's rude? There's also this double standard where I complained because a senior frontend developer took 3 months to barely finish a landing page and he implied there was no performance issue, which is a joke. So I really don't know if I am crazy or he's just terribly rude and has some personal issues with me.

Also, is this micromanagement? Because it seems like it is. I don't think is considered to be best practice.

Comment: He's not putting any deadline and he's not even making an effort to make the requirements clear.

Comment: Are you making the effort to clarify the deadlines and requirements?

Comment: He's taking in task from some other managers and he's just giving them to me without making a ticket.

Comment: This question is really hard to follow, and all over the place. What exactly do you want to achieve with this question? If we give you our opinion of whether he is rude or micromanaging, what follows? As-is, it's gunna get closed.

Comment: I just want to know if this is expected behavior or best practice, because I find him to be infuriating, and I want to know if I have a good reason to be infuriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some people like to Crisis Manage

My experience is that people like this expect you to jump around and react to their demands.  Just respond "no, because I'm working on this other hair-on-fire thing you assigned me yesterday.  How would you like to prioritize my work?" (don't say hair-on-fire to your boss, lol) People like this tend to then go away and find someone who will run around and bounce off the walls managing crises like them.